# Perl Socket Conditional doesn't work

Tags: perl, sockets, client-server, conditional-statements

I'm trying to create a server and client wherein the server returns a diferent message to the client according to what client sends. If the client makes the connection but sends nothing, the server will return message 1 and in case the client sends some data, the server will return message 2. But this doesn't work, the client stays waiting the data and nothing prints.

Client:

```
use IO::Socket;

my $sock = new IO::Socket::INET (
    PeerAddr => '10.1.1.28',
    PeerPort => '7070',
    Proto => 'tcp' ); 

if (@ARGV != "") {
    print $sock "$ARGV[0] $ARGV[1]";

} else {
    $data = <$sock>;
    print $data;
}       

$sock->close;
```

Server

```
use IO::Socket;
my $sock = new IO::Socket::INET (
    LocalHost => '10.1.1.28',
    LocalPort => '7070',
    Proto => 'tcp',
    Listen => '1',
    );

while(1) {
    my $new_sock = $sock->accept();

    if (<$new_sock> ne "") {        
        print $new_sock "conection with parameters";
    } else {
        print $new_sock "default message";  
};
```

Comment: Always use `use strict; use warnings;`

Comment: "If clint make the connection but don't send nothing, the server return message 1", no it doesn't. The server waits for the client to send something unconditionally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to chomp

```
use IO::Socket; 
use Data::Dumper; 
my $sock = new IO::Socket::INET(
    LocalPort => '7070',
    Proto     => 'tcp',
    Listen    => '1',
);

while (1) { 
    my $new_sock = $sock->accept();
    my $in       = <$new_sock>;
    chomp($in);         
    if ( $in ne "" ) {  

        print Dumper($in);  
        print $new_sock "conection with parameters";
    }                       
    else {
        print $new_sock "default message";
    }
}
```